# Printing out a 3D array in c

Tags: c, arrays

So I'm trying to printout a seven-segment display using an array with three dimensions:

I stumble upon this post, explaining the array structure for a seven-segment display: 
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/94140-seven-segment-display.html

This is what I'd want to print out:

```
char array[9][10][20]
```

But I just can't seem to figure out how exactly to print it out. Furthermore, I'm stumped on how would I print out just one of the seven-segment numbers (for example just the '5')?

I think that I'm going to need three for loops, but I'm just not sure how to implement the third one. Any examples that I've found are only 2d, which I kind of get, but that last dimension is confusing me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overthink it. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char array[9][10][20] =
     {
          {" ### ","    "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"     ","    "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {" ### ","    "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
     };

int main(void) {
  int ii, jj, kk;

  // printing '3':

  for(ii = 0; ii<9; ii++) {
    printf("%s\n", array[ii][3]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 ### 
    #
    #
    #
 ### 
    #
    #
    #
 ###
```

Why does this work?

First, let's look at the array used to create the segments. It's a 9x10x20 array of characters.

In fact, while the last dimension was set to `20`, it consists entirely of strings that are length `6` (`5+1` for the terminating `'\0'`).  To print out an individual digit, you want to print just the strings belonging to that digit - which the above example does for the digit `3`.

It gets trickier if you want to print out a longer string of numbers, since you would have to loop over each digit on a per-row basis.  Here is how you might do that for the number `12345`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char array[9][10][20] =
     {
          {" ### ","    "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","   #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"     ","    "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","   #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {" ### ","    "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
     };

int main(void) {
  int ii, jj, kk;

  // printing '3':

  for(ii = 0; ii<9; ii++) {
    printf("%s\n", array[ii][3]);
  }
  // print '12345'
  int numToPrint = 12345;

  char numBuf[20];
  sprintf(numBuf, "%d", numToPrint);

  for(ii=0; ii<9; ii++) {
    for(jj=0; jj < strlen(numBuf); jj++) {
      printf("%s ", array[ii][numBuf[jj]-'0']);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Output of the second part:

```
      ###   ###         ###  
   #     #     # #   # #     
   #     #     # #   # #     
   #     #     # #   # #     
      ###   ###   ###   ###  
   # #         #     #     # 
   # #         #     #     # 
   # #         #     #     # 
      ###   ###         ###
```

Note - I use the `sprintf` function to turn the integer into a string - then I can find each corresponding digit by looking at each character in the string and subtracting `'0'`. In "real" code you would of course check that you don't exceed array boundaries, and you would probably want to include a string for a decimal point and `+` and `-` signs to make something a little more flexible - but I hope you get the idea from this.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks for the through reply!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, but here is a way to display wanted number.

```
int numberToDisplay = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", array[i][numberToDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top level we have:

```
array =
     {
          {" ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"     ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {" ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},    
     };
```

This array has 9 elements, corresponding to the rows of the SSD digit ASCII art. For example:

```
array[2] =
    {
        "#   #", /* 3rd row of digit '0' */
        "    #", /* 3rd row of digit '1' */
        "    #", /* 3rd row of digit '2' */
        "    #", /* 3rd row of digit '3' */
        "#   #", /* 3rd row of digit '4' */
        "#    ", /* 3rd row of digit '5' */
        "#    ", /* 3rd row of digit '6' */
        "    #", /* 3rd row of digit '7' */
        "#   #", /* 3rd row of digit '8' */
        "#   #", /* 3rd row of digit '9' */
    };
```

Indexing this array will pick which digit to print the 3rd row from. Thus, to print multiple digits, we need something like:

```
char array[9][10][20] = 
     {
          {" ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"#   #","    #","    #","    #","#   #","#    ","#    ","    #","#   #","#   #"},
          {"     ","     "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {"#   #","    #","#    ","    #","    #","    #","#   #","    #","#   #","    #"},
          {" ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### ","     "," ### "," ### "},    
     };

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    char number[] = "345";
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {                         /* For each row...*/
        for (j = 0; number[j] != '\0'; j++) {         /* Print the nth row of each digit */
            printf("%s ", array[i][number[j] - '0']);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```